# WP : Stray start tag HTML in validator?

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

I am trying to validate this HTML document in http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input but I am getting the following errors:

```
 Line 10, Column 71: Stray start tag html.
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" class="no-js">
```

This is the HTML I am inputting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--[if IE 7]><html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="ie ie7 no-js" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="ie ie8 no-js" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!--><html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js" /><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<meta>` tag here implies an additional `<html>` and `<head>` tag before.

According to the HTML5 standard some tags are optional. `<html>` and `<head>` are such tags. You can drop them, but the parser will insert them, where needed. In your case they are needed before the `<meta>` tag, because `<meta>` is defined as a child element to the `<head>` tag, which in turn is a child of `<html>`.

So what the validator actually sees is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--[if IE 7]><html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="ie ie7 no-js" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="ie ie8 no-js" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!--><html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js" /><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

Now it is obvious, why it complains about the "second" `<html>` tag.

The solution would be to just change the ordering of your tags. Put the `<html>` and `<head>` tag before the `<meta>` tag, and you should be fine.

Comment: there are 2 <head> ??

Comment: The one explicit, you give in the code, and the other implicit, which is added by the parser. So yes, actually you have 2 `<head>` tags in there.

Comment: @user3626111, what did you actually do? You just need to move the `<meta...>` tag so that it is after the `<head>` tag. If problems remain, show the exact code you tried.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ontha.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices

Comment: @user3626111 Look at the results and see the comment for the second error: "Cannot recover after last error. **Any further errors will be ignored.**" That's why you don't see those other errors, before fixing the `<meta>` tag position.

Comment: Go through the errors and fix them one by one? From a first glance, many of them are just HTML properties, which should be CSS properties nowadays.